# Reading a grib2 dataset with 4 dimensions and 2 variables with R

Tags: r, raster, spatial, terra

I am trying to read a GRIB2 file with R. This file is a probabilistic meteorological forecast : 2 variables, 114 lead times, 18 longitudes, 24 latitudes, and 50 members.

I didn't manage to do it so I used a Python routine to convert the grib file into netCDF, and then I read the netCDF with R. But this raises many issues : I have to use python and specific packages, which are not available in a portable version. And I need the process to be run on a portable environment. I saw that I could read GRIB2 files with the terra package in R, with this post : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396408/how-to-properly-extract-point-data-from-multi-raster-grib-file-in-r

Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to find a way to properly extract my data, with all these dimensions.

```
  require(terra)
  
  ## Isn't it possible to get them automatically ?
  lat_prev <- (rev(seq(42.875,48.625,by=0.25)))
  lon_prev <- (seq(3.375,7.625,by=0.25))
  
  latlon <- expand.grid(lon=lon_prev, lat=lat_prev)
  
  latlons <- terra::vect(latlon, geom=c('lon','lat'), crs="+proj=longlat")
  ## Not sure about that...
  pts <- project(latlons, "+proj=lcc +lat_0=38.5 +lon_0=262.5 +lat_1=38.5 +lat_2=38.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371229 +units=m")
  
  grib_data <- terra::rast(destfile_CF)
  ## gives a data frame of NaN
  e1 <- extract(grib_data, pts)
```

This is an example of grb2 file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1euIvEpDP4f4Kqhdnnswba6VjD1i8EvzY/view?usp=sharing

I believe I need to ask an extraction on all my dimensions, but they are not all spatial points (class SpatialVector), so what is the object to create ? Thanks for your help

UPDATE thanks to solution

```
require(terra)
require(dplyr)
require(data.table)
require(stats)

destfile <- "C:/Users/XXX/Documents/Example_file.grb"

##Downloading file
grib_data <- terra::rast(destfile)
print(grib_data)

## Convert to data frame
df <- as.data.frame(grib_data, xy=TRUE)

## Colnames is a combination of members (50) X time (57) X variables (2)
colNames <- paste(names(grib_data), as.character(time(grib_data)), sep="_")
colnames(df) <- c("lon", "lat", colNames)

df2 <- data.table::melt(as.data.table(df), c("lon", "lat"))

## Split variable and time
df2$time_UTC <- sub(".*_", "", df2$variable)    
df2$variable <- sub("_.*", "", df2$variable)   

## Add members
df2 <- df2 %>% group_by(lon, lat, variable, time_UTC) %>% mutate(member=(1:length(value)))

##Convert to array
df_array <- stats::xtabs(value~lon+lat+variable+member+time_UTC, df2, drop=F)
```

Comment: May I ask which nwp product you're using? Guess you did not create the file yourself.

Comment: It is CEP-EPS for total precipitation and 2 metre temperature (from ECMWF)

Comment: Dealing with some EPS data myself at the moment and can only recommend to reassign proper layer names via `names()` in order to be able to subset your stack without issues based on relevant members and start / forecasting times to be able to differentiate between specific model runs. At the moment, my names look sth like this: "ICON-EU-EPS M17 REF 2022-11-22 00:00 FORECAST 2022-11-22 18:00".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of `terra` extracts the time for this file. That makes it a little easier to keep track of things as falk-env mentions.

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.33
f <- "example_file.grb2"
r <- rast(f)
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 23, 17, 5700  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#extent      : 3.375, 7.625, 42.875, 48.625  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat Coordinate System imported from GRIB file 
#source      : example_file.grb2 
#names       : SFC=G~2*s)], SFC=G~2*s)], SFC=G~2*s)], SFC=G~2*s)], SFC=G~2*s)], SFC=G~2*s)], ... 
#unit        :  kg/(m^2*s),  kg/(m^2*s),  kg/(m^2*s),  kg/(m^2*s),  kg/(m^2*s),  kg/(m^2*s), ... 
#time        : 2022-10-18 to 2022-11-01 UTC
```

You can get the cell values with

```
names(r) <- as.character(time(r))
v <- as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE)
dim(v)
#[1]  391 5702

v[1:3, 1:5]
#     x    y 2022-10-18 00:00:00 2022-10-18 00:00:00.1 2022-10-18 06:00:00
#1 3.50 48.5                   0              1.976562          0.05817413
#2 3.75 48.5                   0              3.436768          0.06186676
#3 4.00 48.5                   0              3.603271          0.08237457
```

And here are the time stamps

```
plot(time(r), type="l")
```

[image]

Perhaps that matches the 50 members and two variables, with the first variable organized by member, and the second variable organized by time?

But GDAL sees no sub-datasets

```
sds(f)
#Error: [sds] file has no sub-datasets
```

And the GDALinfo metadata does not show that either. Unless it is encoded in the GRIB_PDS_PDTN and GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_NUMBERS and PDS_TEMPLATE_ASSEMBLED_VALUES; see [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/grib.html), then [here](https://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/docs/grib2/grib2_doc/grib2_table4-0.shtml) and [here](https://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/docs/grib2/grib2_doc/grib2_temp4-11.shtml).

```
d <- describe(f)
d[31:45]
# [1] "Band 1 Block=17x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined"                                                                                                                                          
# [2] "  Description = 0[-] SFC=\"Ground or water surface\""                                                                                                                                           
# [3] "  Metadata:"                                                                                                                                                                                    
# [4] "    GRIB_COMMENT=Total precipitation rate [kg/(m^2*s)]"                                                                                                                                         
# [5] "    GRIB_DISCIPLINE=0(Meteorological)"                                                                                                                                                          
# [6] "    GRIB_ELEMENT=TPRATE"                                                                                                                                                                        
# [7] "    GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS=0"                                                                                                                                                                    
# [8] "    GRIB_IDS=CENTER=98(ECMWF) SUBCENTER=0 MASTER_TABLE=27 LOCAL_TABLE=0 SIGNF_REF_TIME=1(Start_of_Forecast) REF_TIME=2022-10-18T00:00:00Z PROD_STATUS=0(Operational) TYPE=4(Perturbed_forecast)"
# [9] "    GRIB_PDS_PDTN=11"                                                                                                                                                                           
#[10] "    GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_ASSEMBLED_VALUES=1 52 0 255 153 65535 255 1 0 1 -127 -2147483647 255 -127 -2147483647 255 1 51 2022 10 18 0 0 0 1 0 1 2 1 0 255 0"                                        
#[11] "    GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_NUMBERS=1 52 0 255 153 255 255 255 1 0 0 0 0 1 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 1 51 7 230 10 18 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 255 0 0 0 0"                
#[12] "    GRIB_REF_TIME=1666051200"                                                                                                                                                                   
#[13] "    GRIB_SHORT_NAME=0-SFC"                                                                                                                                                                      
#[14] "    GRIB_UNIT=[kg/(m^2*s)]"                                                                                                                                                                     
#[15] "    GRIB_VALID_TIME=1666051200"  

tail(d, 15)
# [1] "Band 5700 Block=17x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined"                                                                                                                                       
# [2] "  Description = 0[-] SFC=\"Ground or water surface\""                                                                                                                                           
# [3] "  Metadata:"                                                                                                                                                                                    
# [4] "    GRIB_COMMENT=Total precipitation rate [kg/(m^2*s)]"                                                                                                                                         
# [5] "    GRIB_DISCIPLINE=0(Meteorological)"                                                                                                                                                          
# [6] "    GRIB_ELEMENT=TPRATE"                                                                                                                                                                        
# [7] "    GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS=1209600"                                                                                                                                                              
# [8] "    GRIB_IDS=CENTER=98(ECMWF) SUBCENTER=0 MASTER_TABLE=27 LOCAL_TABLE=0 SIGNF_REF_TIME=1(Start_of_Forecast) REF_TIME=2022-10-18T00:00:00Z PROD_STATUS=0(Operational) TYPE=4(Perturbed_forecast)"
# [9] "    GRIB_PDS_PDTN=11"                                                                                                                                                                           
#[10] "    GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_ASSEMBLED_VALUES=1 52 0 255 153 65535 255 1 336 1 -127 -2147483647 255 -127 -2147483647 255 50 51 2022 11 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 2 1 0 255 0"                                      
#[11] "    GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_NUMBERS=1 52 0 255 153 255 255 255 1 0 0 1 80 1 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 50 51 7 230 11 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 255 0 0 0 0"               
#[12] "    GRIB_REF_TIME=1666051200"                                                                                                                                                                   
#[13] "    GRIB_SHORT_NAME=0-SFC"                                                                                                                                                                      
#[14] "    GRIB_UNIT=[kg/(m^2*s)]"                                                                                                                                                                     
#[15] "    GRIB_VALID_TIME=1667260800"
```

It seems like the GDAL driver may need some improvement; but it is hard to say based on this alone. What does a "grib-tool" say there is in this file?

Comment: Wow, it's almost frightening how fast `terra` is evolving.. ! ;-)

Comment: That's really weird because there is no sign of the 2nd variable, even if I use Panoply to read the Grib2 file. But I have 5700 columns which correspond to 50 membres X 57 hours X 2 (variables ?). And the other thing that I don't understand is that if I count the number of dates with "table(time(grib_data))", I have 150 times the first date, 100 times all the other one, and 50 times the last one... In the UPDATE of my post, you can see what Panoply gives me.

Comment: My bad, my example file has a problem but the loading worked ! I've added the few lines that allowed me to construct the final data in the first post. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'd say data extraction per se from GRIB2 files using `{terra}` is possible, but results could be more meaningful in this case in my opinion, i.e. come in a more structured way. But this is mainly an issue related to the amount of layers, as you mentioned.

Importing data is quite self-explanatory:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.17

r <- rast("example_file.grb2")
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 23, 17, 5700  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent      : 3.375, 7.625, 42.875, 48.625  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat Coordinate System imported from GRIB file 
#> source      : example_file.grb2 
#> names       : SFC=G~2*s)], SFC=G~2*s)], SFC=G~2*s)], SFC=G~2*s)], SFC=G~2*s)], SFC=G~2*s)], ... 
#> unit        :  kg/(m^2*s),  kg/(m^2*s),  kg/(m^2*s),  kg/(m^2*s),  kg/(m^2*s),  kg/(m^2*s), ...
```

As you can see, you get a SpatRaster object with 5,700 (=114*50) layers. So basically your lead times and members are included, but your second variable is not. Unfortunately, the time attribute is also undefined. This would have been quite handy here, in my opinion, if one could subset data based on the nwp timestamps.

```r
names(r) |> unique()
#> [1] "SFC=Ground or water surface; Total precipitation rate [kg/(m^2*s)]"

time(r) |> head(20)
#>  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be an issue with your special file, but with GRIB2 in general. I also tried importing another forecast dataset and faced the same issues.

However, `gdalinfo example_file.grb2` clearly shows that this metadata is available, c.f. attributes `GRIB_REF_TIME` and `GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS`.

This being said, if you knew the exact order of the layers, I'd construct new layer names using `names(r) <- c(...)` consisting of e.g. a timestamp representing the reference time, followed by the leadtime and some member information. This way you would be able to subset your raster stack and e.g. extract all relevant layers related to the nwp output originating at "2022-10-18 22:00 UTC" - or something like this.

Extraction of values at point locations works nevertheless - you just need to know the order of your layers to get meaningful results. The resulting data frame consists of 10 rows (= your locations) and 5701 columns (1 ID, 5700 extracted values; 1 per layer).

```r
# generate some points
p <- spatSample(r, 10, as.points = TRUE, values = FALSE)
p
#>  class       : SpatVector 
#>  geometry    : points 
#>  dimensions  : 10, 0  (geometries, attributes)
#>  extent      : 3.75, 6.5, 43.75, 48.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#>  coord. ref. : lon/lat Coordinate System imported from GRIB file

# extract values
res <- extract(r, p)
dim(res)
#> [1]   10 5701
```

If you're struggling to create SpatVector points, you could also create simple feature objects using `{sf}` and convert them afterwards using `terra::vect()`.