# Reading a grib2 dataset without loss of metata with R

Tags: r, raster, spatial, terra

My question follows this previous question, that has been partially answered : [Reading a grib2 dataset with 4 dimensions and 2 variables with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74115590/reading-a-grib2-dataset-with-4-dimensions-and-2-variables-with-r)

I am trying to read a GRIB2 file with R. This file is a probabilistic meteorological forecast : 10 variables, 1 lead time, 17 longitudes, 23 latitudes, and 51 members.

I can extract that thanks to the terra package and this script :

```
require(terra)
require(dplyr)
require(data.table)
require(stats)

destfile <- "C:/Users/XXX/Documents/example_grib_file_3"

##Downloading file
grib_data <- terra::rast(destfile)
print(grib_data)

## Convert to data frame
df <- as.data.frame(grib_data, xy=TRUE)

## Colnames is a combination of members (50) X time (57) X variables (2)
colNames <- paste(names(grib_data), as.character(time(grib_data)), sep="_")
colnames(df) <- c("lon", "lat", colNames)

df2 <- data.table::melt(as.data.table(df), c("lon", "lat"))

## Split variable and time
df2$time_UTC <- sub(".*_", "", df2$variable)    
df2$variable <- sub("_.*", "", df2$variable)   

## Add members
df2 <- df2 %>% group_by(lon, lat, variable, time_UTC) %>% mutate(member=(1:length(value)))

##Convert to array
df_array <- stats::xtabs(value~lon+lat+variable+member+time_UTC, df2, drop=F)
```

The BIG problem is that I can't retrieve the metadata concerning the perturbation number (member). For now, variables and members are mixed, giving 500 columns, with the variable name repeated 50 times. The member is not always at the same position along the other dimension (variable). For example, one particular member is in position 6 for temperature data, and position 50 for precipitation data.

So the line "Add member" in my code is totally irrelevant and needs the "perturbation number" to arrange the array. If I use eccodes, there is a field called "perturbationNumber", how can I retrieve it from terra and R ?

The example file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kUfTdtAdNJpugMpPhdQ6tY4QZaZlUQcA/view?usp=sharing

The example file in grib2 : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zsf8uajm5AOXTiCus6PyANZAsJ5cKsc1/view?usp=sharing

These are the different parameters retrieved using eccodes with Python :

```
grib_ls -l 48.5,3.5,1 -p paramId,name,typeOfLevel,level,dataDate,stepRange,dataType,shortName,step,perturbationNumber PATH_TO_FILE

paramId             name                typeOfLevel         level               dataDate            stepRange           dataType            shortName           step                perturbationNumber   value
167                 2 metre temperature  surface             0                   20230124            0                   pf                  2t                  0                   35                  273.517
167                 2 metre temperature  surface             0                   20230124            0                   pf                  2t                  0                   3                   273.589
167                 2 metre temperature  surface             0                   20230124            0                   pf                  2t                  0                   50                  273.229
etc...
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: can you add your python code and show what is returned as text (please do not include screenshots)

Comment: I've added it at the end of my question. The number I am looking for is the perturbationNumber just before the value in the table (35, 3, 50, ...).

Comment: Before the dev version of terra apparently was able to handle this natively, i was making use of `terra::describe()` in combination with `stringr::str_detect()` to extract relevant meta data from grib2.

Answer (score 1):

With your example file

```
f <- "example_grib_file_3"
library(terra)
#terra 1.7.5
x <- rast(f)
```

This is the metadata that is available

```
names(x)[1]
#[1] "SFC (Ground or water surface); 2 metre temperature [C]"
time(x)[1]
#[1] "2023-01-24 UTC"
units(x)[1]
#[1] "C"
```

And with version 1.7-5 (currently the development version) you can also get raw metadata

```
metadata(x)[[1]]
#     [,1]                    [,2]                     
#[1,] "GRIB_COMMENT"          "2 metre temperature [C]"
#[2,] "GRIB_ELEMENT"          "2T"                     
#[3,] "GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS" "0"                      
#[4,] "GRIB_REF_TIME"         "1674518400"             
#[5,] "GRIB_SHORT_NAME"       "0-SFC"                  
#[6,] "GRIB_UNIT"             "[C]"                    
#[7,] "GRIB_VALID_TIME"       "1674518400"
```

I do not know if there are ways to get other metdata from this file but in principle that is possible: see your previous question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - again. The "description" function does not work but even with rgdal, I couldn't find any metadata concerning the perturbationNumber... The variable is just repeated 50 times (with nlyr = 502 = lon, lat, 50 member X 10 variables). It seems to be lost when reading the file in R.

Comment: @Chika: `gdalinfo` does recognize 502 bands present in your file, but there does not seem to be any additional information per band apart from the one given by `metadata(x)`, see above. Are you sure this information is harcoded somewhere in the metadata and ecCodes does not simply derive this implicitly by incrementation? E.g. the 5th member has to be on position 5 among all "Total precipitation" layers. Otherwise, this would be an absolute mess, imho.

Comment: I can confirm that it is not implicitly derived, and it is a harcoded information in the metadata, because membre 5 is in position 10 for precipitation and position 48 for temperature... You can see it in the example at the end of my post, the perturbationNumber does not match the line number.

Comment: If I convert the file into a GRIB2 file (it is a GRIB1 file) with python and ecCodes (GRIB2:$ grib_set -w edition=1 -s edition=2 in_file out_file ), and I use metadata(grib_file) with terra (R), I have some more information. I have a [7,] "GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_ASSEMBLED_VALUES" where the perturbationNumber seems to be mixed with other metada. So a part of the problem comes from the Grib1 extension ?

Comment: Not the extension, but the format. Apparently GDAL can better read GRIB2 than GRIB1. It would be helpful if you also shared the GRIB2 file.

Comment: Yes, it is here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zsf8uajm5AOXTiCus6PyANZAsJ5cKsc1/view?usp=sharing